# Could not create Makefile for some reason - Trying to install Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rubygems, github-linguist

I'm having some trouble installing a Ruby Gem called Lingust for my Mac. I get the error message below and have no idea how to solve the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
gem install github-linguist
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing github-linguist:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/kanery/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby -r./siteconf20151008-9054-b4exbs.rb extconf.rb
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... yes
checking for cmake... no
ERROR: CMake is required to build Rugged.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/Users/kanery/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby
  --use-system-libraries

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kanery/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rugged-0.24.0b0 for inspection.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [installation instructions of Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged#install), you can see that both CMake and `pkg-config` are required. Looking at your error message, it seems like CMake is not installed on your system.

If you are using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), you can install it by running

```
brew install cmake
```

Or you can install it from the source following [these instructions](https://cmake.org/install/).